# CS1525 C# Invalid expression term 'string'

Tags: c#

I have this error and I have no ideo about what should I do

The aim is when I click to button, it should read the word in textbox and save it into the string variable by its new factor.I have the error oin the topic

```
 private void panel_button_kelimeekle_kaydet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(panel_checkbox_ing.Checked)
            {
                string (panel_textbox_kelimeekle_yab.Text) = Ingkelimeler[(Ingkelimeler.Length+1)];

            }

}
```

Comment: What you need is a basic c# tutorial. The Microsoft Docs is a great place to get started. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/getting-started/)

Comment: You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of C#. I'd recommend finding a good tutorial to learn from before diving into anything.

Comment: I agree to the basic tutorial idea

Comment: Im sorry but "Ingkelimeler" is not telling me anything in this... is this your control ? your variable name? what? and you didnt name your variable.

Comment: Here's a great C# tutorial: https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/c-fundamentals-for-absolute-beginners-16169?l=Lvld4EQIC_2706218949

Comment: Also, when you do get this running, `Ingkelimeler[(Ingkelimeler.Length+1)]` is probably going to give you an index out of range error.

Comment: While this isn't an absolute "must", I would recommend you write your code in English, or at least write your Stack Overflow posts in English. People will get a much better understanding of what is going on that way.

Answer (score 2):

If `panel_textbox_kelimeekle_yab` is already a textbox on your form, then you don't need to declare its type when you assign a value to it. C# thinks you're trying to declare a new `string` variable.

Change that line of code to

```
panel_textbox_kelimeekle_yab.Text = Ingkelimeler[(Ingkelimeler.Length+1)];
```

This probably won't solve all your problems, but at least it will get you on to the next error message. (You probably mean `Length-1` in your array index, but there's really no way for us to know.)

Comment: `Ingkelimeler[(Ingkelimeler.Length+1)];` = IndexOutOfRangeException

Comment: Somehow I don't think that's going to work with that index...

Comment: @FraukeNonnenmacher That's up to the OP to solve.

Comment: Ron, how can you get the item 2 positions after the end of the list? The accessible range is 0 (inclusive) to length (exclusive).